# Java Function not execution all the way

Tags: java, android, function

I'm new to Java and have no idea what is happening here.

I have an application where the user chooses a date and the app would find the difference in weeks/days and return a phrase like "3 weeks and 4 days"

I start off by sending the date the user chose into *TimeDifferenceCalc.java*

**main.java**

```
TimeDifferenceCalc TimeDiffCalcObj = new TimeDifferenceCalc();
TimeDiffCalcObj.main(endMonth, endDay, endYear);
```

Everything there works fine and it returns the string so I send it back to the main java class

**TimeDifferenceCalc.java**

```
main mainObj = new main();
mainObj.setPreviewDate(statement); //statement = the string ("3 weeks and 4 days")
```

That also works fine, the function below is what the code above just called.

**main.java**

```
public void setPreviewDate(String statement) {
    Log.v(TAG, "RECIEVED -> [setPreviewDate] || STATEMENT = " + statement);
    final TextView previewText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.create_preview);
    String finalText = "A " + difficultyText + " " + what + " " + selectedClass + statement;
    previewText.setText(finalText);
    Log.v(TAG, "WENT THROUGH -> [setPreviewDate] || STATEMENT = " + statement);
}
```

What I'm trying to do with the function above is set a set the text of a TextView to the String "finalText" (all the variables in the string are set).

**The Problem**

Once *setPreviewDate* is called it will *Log.v* just fine

```
RECIEVED -> [setPreviewDate] || STATEMENT = 3 weeks and 4 days
```

But the function won't run or get passed the line...

```
final TextView previewText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.create_preview);
```

So nothing below that line will run it just stops with no errors.

Comment: if `main ` is extending Activity then calling a method by creating object of Class which is extending Activity will causing NPE exception.

Comment: try passing object of `main.java` when you make new instance of `TimeDifferenceCalc.java`. And then using that object, call `setPreviewDate()` method.

Comment: @DhrumilPatel can you please provide an example.

Comment: When you instantiate `TimeDifferenceCalc.java` in `main.java`, simply pass `this` as argument. e.g. `TimeDifferenceCalc obj = new TimeDifferenceCalc(this)` .

Comment: Make constructor in `TimeDifferenceCalc.java` as follow `main mainObj; ` `public TimeDifferenceCalc(main mainObj){ this.mainObj = mainObj; }` And then call the method using this object, `mainObj.setPreviewDate(statement);` Try this, and let me know if you run into any problem.